# variable defined inside __init__ not reading

Tags: python

What I have understood is to define variables inside **init** magic method. I did but the next method is not reading it.

Any help?

```
class Foo:

    var = 9

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.i = a
        self.j = b

    def add(self, a, b):
        print a+b

bar = Foo(5, 5)  # create object

print bar.var  # access class variable
```

o/p:

9

Why does it not print

10

9

Comment: Why would it print 10? Where do you think that would come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run the code inside `add`, you must call it.

```
bar = Foo(5, 5)  # create object
bar.add(5,5)
print bar.var  # access class variable
```

Comment: does all variables need to be defined in __init__ method?

Comment: @Riomario, All the instance variables (variables attached to an object) need to be. Function parameters and class-level variables do not need to be.

Comment: On: bar = Foo(5, 5) , is bar an object? (5,5) are instance variable and var=9 class-level variable?

Comment: @Riomario, Yes, bar is an object. The instance variables are `self.i` and `self.j`. Yes, `var` is a class-level variable.

Comment: if self.i and self.j are instance variables then what are a and b?

Comment: @Riomario, Those are parameters of the function, which only live until the function exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74300/discussion-between-rio-mario-and-merlin2011).

Answer (score 3):

You called the variables `self.i` and `self.j`, not `a` and `b`, so that's how you need to refer to them. `add()` should be defined like this:

```
def add(self):
    print self.i+self.j
```

Comment: But more to the point, OP hasn't even called the `add` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right. I didn't even notice that when I first read the question.

Comment: does all variables need to be defined in __init__ method?